# Telegram checking and adding to contacts?

Tags: javascript, python, telegram

I need your help.
I had 40k of mobile numbers and i need to do few things:

- Check if this numbers have tg account
- Add this account to contact list.

Can anybody helps me, how i can do it. Or with examples of codes.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using pyrogram,

To check if the entity has a telegram account : `await app.get_users(mobile_number)`

Read More : [Pyrogram get_users()](https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/methods/get_users)

To add entity to contacts: `await app.add_contact("useridorusername", "Contactname", phone_number="6969696")`

Read More : [Pyrogram add_contact()](https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/methods/add_contact)